# bash - case-insensitive matching of variable

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression, case-sensitivity

This syntax prints "linux" when variable equals "no":

```
 [[ $LINUX_CONF = no ]] && echo "linux"
```

How would I use regular expressions (or similar) in order to make the comparison case insensitive?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Standard sh

No need to use that `ksh`-style `[[...]]` command, you can use the standard `sh` `case` construct here:

```
case $LINUX_CONF in
  ([Nn][Oo]) echo linux;;
  (*)        echo not linux;;
esac
```

Or naming each possible case individually:

```
case $LINUX_CONF in
  (No | nO | NO | no) echo linux;;
  (*)                 echo not linux;;
esac
```

### bash

For a `bash`-specific way to do case-insensitive matching, you can do:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
[[ $LINUX_CONF = no ]] && echo linux
```

Or:

```
[[ ${LINUX_CONF,,} = no ]] && echo linux
```

(where `${VAR,,}` is the syntax to convert a string to lower case).

You can also force a variable to be converted to lowercase upon assignment with:

```
typeset -l LINUX_CONF
```

That also comes from ksh and is also supported by `bash` and `zsh`.

More variants with other shells:

### zsh

```
set -o nocasematch
[[ $LINUX_CONF = no ]] && echo linux
```

(same as in `bash`).

```
set -o extendedglob
[[ $LINUX_CONF = (#i)no ]] && echo linux
```

(less dangerous than making *all* matches case insensitive)

```
[[ ${(L)LINUX_CONF} = no ]] && echo linux
[[ $LINUX_CONF:l = no ]] && echo linux
```

(convert to lowercase operators)

```
set -o rematchpcre
[[ $LINUX_CONF =~ '^(?i)no\z' ]]
```

(PCRE syntax)

### ksh93

```
[[ $LINUX_CONF = ~(i)no ]]
```

or

```
[[ $LINUX_CONF = ~(i:no) ]]
```

Note that all approaches above other than `[nN][oO]` to do case insensitive matching depend on the user's locale. Not all people around the world agree on what the uppercase version of a given letter is, even for ASCII ones.

In practice for the ASCII ones, at least on GNU systems, the deviations from the English rules seem to be limited to the `i` and `I` letters and whether the dot is there or not on the uppercase or lowercase version.

What that means is that `[[ ${VAR,,} = oui ]]` is not guaranteed to match on `OUI` in every locale (even when [the bug in current versions of `bash`](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg20451.html) is fixed).

Comment: ok fine but how we do the same in if syntax?

Comment: @yael, why would you want to use `if`? If that's for the `else` part, see edit.

Comment: There is also `[[ "$LINUX_CONF" =~ [Nn][Oo] ]]` (what with the OP specifically asking for a RE).

Comment: @DopeGhoti, or `[[ $LINUX_CONF = [Nn][Oo] ]]` but that has little advantage over the standard `case` syntax.

Comment: In this case, I agree for such a simple comparison.  I, as you did, would simply squash to lower case wtih `${var,,}`.

Comment: +1 for `bash`'s `typeset -l`.  Didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 3):

Keep your existing command but on the line before it run this:

```
LINUX_CONF=$(echo $LINUX_CONF | awk '{ print tolower($0) }')
```

Regardless of the case of the value stored in your variable this will force the replacement value to be lowercase. This results in matching your existing command with only one additional line of code.